# Existe alguma maneira de validar um input no angularJS sem usar formulário?

Tags: angularjs, formulário, validação

Tenho um `input` que desejo validar via AngularJS. Porém esse input não está dentro de um formulário. Por isso, ao tentar acessar as informações de validação do formulário, não obtive sucesso:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="nick" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username.nick" ng-maxlength="10">
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="nick.$error.maxlength">Máximo permitido é 10</span>
</div>
```

Porém se eu fizer dessa forma, funciona:

```
<form name="formUser">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="nick" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username.nick" ng-maxlength="10">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="formUser.nick.$error.maxlength">Máximo permitido é 10</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Nesse caso específico, gostaria de usar a validação semelhante ao segundo exemplo, porém sem formulário.

Existe alguma forma de fazer a validação do angular, sem o uso do formulário?

Comment: Tentou usar a diretiva `ng-form`? Veja mais aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098584/angularjs-input-validation-with-no-enclosing-form

Comment: @abfurlan parece que acabaram de responder isso. Estou sabendo dessa diretiva a pouco tempo.

Comment: Verdade acabei de ver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é usar a diretiva `ng-form`. Desta forma, poderia ficar assim:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form="nick">
    <input name="nick" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username.nick" ng-maxlength="10">
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="nick.$error.maxlength">Máximo permitido é 10</span>
</div>
```

Essa Diretiva possui todas as capacidades do `form` com `name`, porém ele é mais utilizado em sub grupos. Já vi bastante em form wizard que possui vários steps (passos). Aí, em vez de utilizar vários formulários, eles usam o `ng-form` em etapas que precisam de validação.

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/ny8eLxr8/79/)

Comment: O que essa diretiva faz? Magia?

Comment: Não sei se é algum erro no meu código, mas parece que tem que ter o `name` onde está o `ng-form`.

Comment: coloca assim `ng-form="nick"`, que no caso é o nome do seu form

Comment: Talvez essa tenha sido a confusão, Gabriel. O meu "form" não é nick, pois não tem form. Na verdade, nick é o name o `input` cujo ng-model é igual a `username.nick`.

Comment: Gabriel, testado! É isso mesmo. Vou botar o exemplo aqui, se quiser botar na resposta, fique a vontade +1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ny8eLxr8/78/